# Git Extensions 2.48.05 is not launching - Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: git, git-extensions

Git extensions is not launching in my machine. even uninstalled and re-installed several times. When I saw in the event logger, I found the following issue.

Any clues for a help around?

```
===exception details===
Application: GitExtensions.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException

Stack:

at GitExtensions.Program.HandleConfigurationException(System.Configuration.ConfigurationException)
at GitExtensions.Program.Main()
```

And also

```
Faulting application name: GitExtensions.exe, version: 2.48.5.0, time stamp: 0x55565dce

Faulting module name: GitExtensions.ni.exe, version: 2.48.5.0, time stamp: 0x55565dce

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x00000000000081cd

Faulting process id: 0x159c

Faulting application start time: 0x01d0ff695219067c

Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\GitExtensions.exe

Faulting module path: C:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\GitExtensions\f92d9254dafe25593ad492db7df0e231\GitExtensions.ni.exe

Report Id: 8ffb1394-6b5c-11e5-9366-80000b51fbd9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, till I found out that I damaged my machine.config. I added some oracle configuration, but misplaced a closing tag. After fixing this GitExtensions worked again.

x32: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
x64: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

If this doesn't help, find all gitextensions folder in C:\Users\ and delete them (better backup them before).

Comment: It's not only the closing tag creates this issue, even if you have any problem in machine.config file like XML structure or any duplicate app key or any duplicate node.

Comment: This resolved our issue. Automation of config editor has deleted machine config file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

TO the above fix,if you find any unclosed tags in machine.config or any duplicate entries for database connectivity please comment.

It worked for me thanks @Roland